bootstrapping in the main distro: listing WSL distros: running WSL command wsl.exe C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -l -v --all: context deadline exceeded
enter image description here
i have tried every other solution on internet and it is not working
redownloaded docker and wsl and Linux sub system for windows but nothing working
reinstalled everything but nothing working.
Error Facing :
bootstrapping in the main distro: listing WSL distros: running WSL command wsl.exe C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -l -v --all: context deadline exceeded


Have you tried to Exit docker > powershell wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data and then start it again? This was the trick that worked for me. It was in the error message

Run this in your PowerShell as administrator:
wsl --unregister docker-desktop

